# How to add event with Facebook API without adding post on wall?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So every time new event is added via API to Facebook page, a new wall post is done also to the page. How can you add event without wall post, or is there a way to delete post afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can you add event without wall post". You cannot without un-liking the Facebook page.  The whole reason a user likes a page is to get wall posts from them.